# Does it considered as a good practice to write interfaces in a higher layer?

Tags: separation-of-concerns, clean-architecture, decoupling

I was thinking that would be better to write on the "Application" layer (Business) the interfaces of the unit of work, and their implementations on the "Persistence" layer (DAL). The goal is to make the layers as much decoupled as possible.

Imagine the scenario where you decide to change DAL from EF core to Dapper. How this transition would be less painful? Isn' t better to have the interfaces pronouncing "I need this query, and this, and that, in order to work my business" and map it to the new Data Access Layer?

Comment: Yes, you should declare the interfaces in the layer which should be independent from the infrastructure (i.e. the business layer). You define the contract via the interface and lower level components should implement those interfaces.

With that you can make sure that in your business layer you only have dependencies on stuff that is as well defined in that layer. For instance, you have a repository interface  defined in the business (domain) layer and the implementation of that interface is defined in the persistence layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct and will put your business logic in focus and turn technical details into plug-ins to your business logic.

See also "Clean Architecture" by Robert C. Martin for even deeper thoughts into same direction.

https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Comment: If you have not seen, I advise you to watch this video too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsjsiz2A9mg

Comment: I am inspired exactly from what you proposed from the beginning. Thank you very much!